# rebooting ubuntu remotely

Tags: ssh, reboot

I am accessing my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine remotely via `ssh`. I recently ran the `sudo apt-get upgrade` command and on successful execution, it asked to reboot the system for enforcing some changes made. But I have a problem. I can initiate restart via `reboot` command but my remote system requires someone to press `F12` key on the keyboard immediately after the system is powered up and choose Ubuntu OS from the menu. If this is not done within a couple of seconds then something else is loaded.

But as I mentioned, I am only accessing the system remotely and cannot press systems keys. Can someone thus help me in how to reboot Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the machine have an server console (HP ILO or the like) which allows you to press keys/control the system remotely (including before OS is actually booted)  (*I don't know your hardware, so HP ILO is called iDRAC on Dell... etc*)

Comment: Thankyou but I am very new. But I can execute command on terminal. Can you tell me what command to run on terminal which can help me know this?

Comment: What I suggested is machine specific... if it's a consumer grade machine it won't usually have those features, but enterprise grade hardware (esp. servers) tend to have such features (HP call it *Intergrated Lights Out*, Dell call it *Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller* etc.... ie. a feature on the machine itself)

Comment: No its a consumer grade machine only

Comment: It sounds like you'll just have to delay rebooting until someone is physically present at the server. I can go days or weeks without rebooting because I don't have 30 seconds for boot and a few minutes to reopen applications. Ubuntu doesn't seem to care that it's not rebooted right away.